# Java based user account management system

Tags: java, facebook, twitter, authentication, google-account

I want to implement user account system for my site just like this, http://getsatisfaction.com/login allowing the user to login using Facebook, Twitter, Google, Yahoo and the like. The site is built using Struts 2 + Spring + Hibernate.

Any Java libraries that would help me in building this kind of user account system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look to [JOpenID](http://code.google.com/p/jopenid/), it is an OpenID 2.0 Java 5 implementation for Google Federated Login. Also [SocialAuth](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/) for google, yahoo, windows live, twitter and fb. Or maybe a look to [JanRain Engage](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage) it is free up to 2,500 users.

Comment: SocialAuth looks promising. Have you used Spring Social? It seems to fall on the same category as SocialAuth

Comment: I haven't used it yet, but also looks as a promising tool, integrating with all the power of the Spring family. And is usually easy to find code examples of SS frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

You might try [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java).